# IMAP problem in PHP running in VirtualBox

Tags: php, virtualbox, imap

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine and a PHP script that tries to read the last 30 emails of an user. All worked fine when I had ubuntu as the main os and it manages to run  well on WSL right now, but when I run the script inside a virtual machine it gets timed out.

```
Resource id #4PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993: Connection timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm guessing it is something related to the virtual machine not the php itself but I'm not really sure. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check firewalls.  Does the VM include a firewall setting?  Does the host system?

Comment: @Max VM is ubuntu and I disabled ufw and on host Windows I disabled Windows Defender